# Excel dynamic range name gives error in chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, charts

I am using the name `Summary_values` to dynamically refer to the `CumTotal` column on a separate "Summary" sheet (the `CumTotal` column position can move when the sheet is created).  I need the name in order to plot the value series dynamically on a chart.  The name definition is:

```
Summary_values = INDIRECT(
"'Summary'!" &
ADDRESS(2,MATCH("CumTotal",'Summary'!$1:$1,0),1,1,) &
":" &
ADDRESS(COUNTA('Summary'!$A:$A)-1,MATCH("CumTotal",'Summary'!$1:$1,0),1,1,))
```

When I place the formula in any random cell, the referred range values will display correctly.  However, when I create the name and try to use that name in a chart, I get the error:

> Excel found a problem with one or more formulas in this worksheet

I have also tried with `OFFSET` and received a similar error.